# How do I save a dynamically generated Lisp system in external files?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Basically, I want to be able to generate class definitions, compile the system, and save it for reuse. Would that involve a code walker, or is there a simpler option?

(save-lisp-and-die "isn't going to work for me")

Expanding to explain. I'm generating systems based on OpenAPI definitions, so a system roughly corresponds to an API client.

There will be dozens, if not hundreds of these.

The idea is to NOT keep them all in the image, but load at run time as required.

Comment: Actually, this should be well within the capabilities of `save-lisp-and-die`.  Assuming you have an ASDF system definition, you should be able to do `(asdf:load-system :my-system)` and then `save-lisp-and-die`. If that does not work for you -- you just claim it won't, but don't say why -- please expand your question, and the community can try to help.

Comment: Expanded somewhat.

Comment: Actually, I think prettyfied macroexpansion would work. But I've only seen it implemented in SWANK/SLIME and haven't researched in-depth yet.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  But have you tried just loading them all, and seeing what happens?  Building the image means that the loading time is all paid, and then maybe it's enough that the unused systems will end up getting swapped out.  Anyway, I would try that first, and see if it works. I'm intrigued to know what you are using for OpenAPI clients, btw -- I have used `cl-swagger`, but had to patch it a bunch -- it's really only half-finished.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. Premature optimization, getting ahead of myself. The idea is to build a glue platform for the DevOps ecosystem. Right now it's a zoo, but it should be possible to streamline everything (since most of the tools have APIs) under a single tool. Like in this approach I'm exploring: generate CL client classes and build an integrating DSL on top of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible routes here, and to some extent, I suspect they mainly differ in "the last mile" (as it were).

1. The route you seem to have settled on, run-time definition of classes and functions.
2. A route whereby you generate your function/class forms, but don't go the full way to get them "Live" in the image and instead emit the form(s) to a file.

I suspect that it would be possible to have most of the generating code shared between the two and for the first route have a wrapping macro that effectively returns a PROGN, and in the second calls a function to pretty-print what the macro would have returned on a stream.

Saying that, building a tailored environment and saving it to a "core" file is a pretty good way of getting excellent startup times.